# Android - Trace

Tags: android, events, trace

How can I trace the output from eclipse and the android simulator. I am used to doing it in Flash and actionscript.

In AS3 it would be:
    trace('my trace statement');

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options.  One is the java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler class: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html

```
ConsoleHandler console = new ConsoleHandler();
console.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "Hello logging!"));
```

Another option is using the Log class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

```
Log.v("MyIdentifier", "Hello logging!");
```

Answer (score 0):

In android use the [Log class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to provide this. Simply pick a level you want "debug, warning, info" and then use the function. ie `Log.d("tag","message");

Then this message will appear in the LogCat Eclipse window